# Gmail's Priority Inbox: I changed settings, now I can't get Priority Inbox back

Tags: gmail, account-management

I'd been using the "Priority Inbox" in Gmail where starred messages show first, then new messages, then all read messages.  I changed some settings today, and now I can't figure out how to get back to that view.  Is there a way?  In the settings, there is no longer an "Inbox Type" setting where I can select the priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- click on the gear icon
- select **Settings**
- go to **Inbox**
- as **Inbox type** select **Priority Inbox**
- setup your desired order
- done

[image: 0]

Answer (score 2):

Settings (gear icon) Inbox Tab > Priority inbox first downdrop